# How does one render a list of lists inside an edit form?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an Ecto model with a field:

```
field :coordinates, {:array, {:array, :float}}
```

Now, in the `show` action, this renders just fine, for example as a string `[[0.0, 0.1]]`. However, when I try to render a form for the `edit` function (as a string), I get the following error:

```
** (ArgumentError) lists in Phoenix.HTML and templates may only contain integers representing bytes, binaries or other lists, got invalid entry: 0.0
    (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/safe.ex:80: Phoenix.HTML.Safe.List.to_iodata/1
    (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/safe.ex:49: Phoenix.HTML.Safe.List.to_iodata/1
```

As far as I can tell, this is clashing with the native impl of `Html.Safe`. Though I'm not sure why it clashes in a form, but not in a `show` view.

---

Form code:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label f, "coordinates (e.g: [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4]])", class: "control-label" %>
      <%= text_input f, :coordinates, class: "form-control" %>
      <%= error_tag f, :coordinates %>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
def edit(conn, %{...}) do
  item = Repo.get!(Item, id)
  changeset = Item.changeset(block)
  render(conn, "edit.html", item: item, changeset: changeset)
end
```

Comment: Can you also post the form code?

Comment: Depending on how you want to show it, you can do something like `text_input f, :coordinates, class: "form-control", value: Poison.encode!(f.data.coordinates)`. Do you already have code to parse this in your changeset functions?

Comment: @Dogbert that worked, thanks. -- The changeset returns it in the appropriate data type (`[[0.0, 0.0]]` as array) -- for other fields, I'm `deimpl Html.Safe`, but in this case, it was clashing with the `phoenix_html` use of `List`, so I guess I have to do it manually within the form. -- I still don't understand why it works for `show` but not within the form though :/

Comment: Did you impl `Html.Safe` for this model? I think that's why it works for `show`. That's really not the right way. You should use `Poison.encode!` or `inspect` or something like that.

Comment: no not for the model, just for specific fields which have custom Ecto types.